# php mysql store procedure, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

i've got this code

```
{ <?php
include 'koneksi.php';

$idAgent = $_GET["rqid"];
$ipAgent = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$app = $_GET["app"];
$action = $_GET["action"];

$org = $_GET["org"];
$des = $_GET["des"];

$trainNo = $_GET["train_no"];
$depDate = $_GET["dep_date"];

$query = "SELECT cekRQID('$idAgent','$ipAgent') as jml;";
//echo($query);
$hasil = mysql_query($query);
$data  = mysql_fetch_array($hasil);
$channelOK = $data['jml'];  

if ($channelOK == "1") {
    if ($app == "information" && $action == "get_seat_map") {

        $query="SELECT 0 as err_code, '$org' as org, '$des' as des, '$trainNo' as train_no, $depDate as dep_date ";
        $hasil1 = mysql_query($query);

        $rows1 = array();
        while ($r1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($hasil1)){
            $rows1 = $r1;
        }

        $tglnya = date('Ymd',$depDate); //STR_TO_DATE('$depDate','%Y%m%d')

        $query = mysql_query("CALL GET_SEAT_MAP('$org','$des','$trainNo',STR_TO_DATE('$depDate','%Y%m%d'),@TEST);") or die mysql_error();
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT @TEST;") or die mysql_error();
        //echo($query);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($query))
        {           
            $query = $row[0];
        }

        $hasil = mysql_query($query);
        //echo($query);


        $rows = array();
        $index= 0;
        $bufk0 = "";
        $body = 0;

        while ($r = mysql_fetch_row($hasil)){
            $curfk0 = $r[0].$r[1];
            if( $bufk0 != $curfk0 ){
                $head[$curfk0] = array ( $r[0],$r[1]);  
                $out2[$curfk0][] =  array( $r[2],$r[3],$r[4],$r[5],$r[6],$r[7] );
            } else {                    
                $out2[$curfk0][] =  array( $r[2],$r[3],$r[4],$r[5],$r[6],$r[7] );                   
            }               
            $bufk0 = $r[0].$r[1];
            $bufindex = $index;
            $headindex = $head ;
            $index++;
        }

    }

if (is_array($values)){
    foreach ($head as $key => $val ){
        $final['seat_map'][] = array( $val[0],$val[1], $out2[$key] );       
    }   
}


header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($rows1+$final);
}

?>

}
```

when i'm run this code, i've got some error message :
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/www/html/sgetseatmap.php on line 37

which is in code :

```
$query = mysql_query("CALL GET_SEAT_MAP('$org','$des','$trainNo',STR_TO_DATE('$depDate','%Y%m%d'),@TEST);") or die mysql_error();
```

I just can't figure out why its happening here, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: From looking at your source through "edit", you have `{ <?php` and `?>}` so I'm not sure about your code and where exactly line 37 is.

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: @prix, i've add your code above '$query = mysql_query("CALL GET_SEAT_MAP....', and i've got blank screen

Comment: @daniel, thanks, would you tell me which code and how to solve it ?

Comment: Look at @Barmar answer that's very likely the issue however you should move into MySQLi or PDO ASAP as you are completely vulnerable to SQL injections with your current code and mysql_* library is deprecated.

Comment: @prix, i'm sory, it's not blank screen, but i've got these error, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO... on line 37 ; which is in your code... cmiiw

Comment: @user2707042 I noticed you have this with quotes `'$trainNo' as train_no` but not `$depDate as dep_date`, wondering if this is contributing to the problem.

Comment: @user2707042 Also, why do you have you have `{ <?php` and `?>}` this doesn't look right to me, or do you have something else before and after your posted code?

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if this has anything to do with an improperly stored date and/or the way `GET` is being used. Or both `@TEST);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- its possible that it could happen if for example malformed variables are given, but the problem was already pointed by Barmar.

Comment: @Prix The OP hasn't said anything about it being fixed, after using Barmar's answer, which I find strange. Oh well, let the OP figure it out. Cheers

Comment: @Fred-ii- he never said he tried barmar's answer on the comments. What he tried was what I sent him early for debugging and I already deleted it as barmar have the right answer which can be easily tested to see that is right.

Comment: @Prix Got it. It seems like Barmar is still at it with the OP. Sure hope a solution's going to be found.

Answer (score 3):

You have the following on two lines:

```
or die mysql_error();
```

While you should be applauded for checking for errors (it's pretty rare in the questions we see), that syntax is wrong. `die` is a function, so the argument must be in parenthese:

```
or die(mysql_error());
```

On the other hand, you also should stop using the mysql_xxx functions, as they're deprecated. You should use PDO or mysqli, and preferably use prepared statements with parameters instead of interpolated strings.

Comment: thanks for your answer basmar, actually i've add 'or die mysql_error();' to catch error in the '$query = mysql_query("CALL GET_SEAT....' 
if I delete, the 'or die mysql_error()', the error code become :

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in <b>/var/www/html/sgetseatmap.php</b> on line <b>42</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in <b>/var/www/html/sgetseatmap.php</b> on line <b>79</b><br />
<br />

Comment: <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: values in <b>/var/www/html/sgetseatmap.php</b> on line <b>95</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: final in <b>/var/www/html/sgetseatmap.php</b> on line <b>103</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Unsupported operand types in <b>/var/www/html/sgetseatmap.php</b> on line <b>103</b><br />

the line 42 is point to : 'while($row = mysql_fetch_row($query))'

Comment: Why are you deleting the `or die mysql_error()`? You need to fix it to the correct syntax, as I showed.

Comment: i've fix with your syntax, but its still error : <br /> <b>Warning</b>: mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in <b>/var/www/html/sgetseatmap.php</b> on line <b>42</b><br /> <br /> ; the line 42 is point to : 'while($row = mysql_fetch_row($query))'

Comment: It's very confusing that you keep reusing the variable `$query` for different things. Please try to make your code understandable if you want other people to help you with it.

Comment: In fact, that reuse is your problem. The line `$query = $row[0]` is overwriting the variable `$query`, so on the next iteration when it does `mysql_fetch_row($query)`, `$query` contains a string instead of a query result. Do you think there's a quota on the number of variables you can use, and you have to conserve names?